# focal ppa.launchpad missing Release file

Tags: apt, raspberrypi

This is a clean stable 20.04 install of the Raspberry PI image.

```
$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for admn:
Ign:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal InRelease
Get:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates InRelease [106 kB]
Err:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8008::15 80]
Hit:5 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports InRelease
Get:6 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security InRelease [107 kB]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I would expect that this PPA should either not be included in the default image, or that the Release file should be there.  I suspect that this is a stripped-down Ubuntu server image, and that the PPA should not be included in the image.

But which, or another option?

Comment: This is a clean 20.04 stable install.  It is possible that the launchpad PPA is not required, but in that case I'd expect that it should not be included by default.

Comment: The Certbot PPA doesn't have 20.04 releases.  20.04 Ubuntu has latest Certbot in the repositories currently, no need to use the PPA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the time of this post, the Certbot PPA does not have Focal builds currently because the latest Certbot is already in the repositories for 20.04 so the PPA isn't needed for 20.04.

Why the RPi image has that PPA included is a mystery to me, but it's not needed currently for 20.04.

Comment: A PPA included in an install image seems like a bug.

Comment: Yes, it does, however the RPi image isn't an *install* image, it's a full blown OS image that can be run directly after copying the image over, unlike the ISO installers for things.  The PPA does not exist on the installer ISOs, etc. for other distros, I don't think.

Comment: As of May 19, "A new version of the `python3-certbot-nginx` package fixing this problem was pushed to the Focal repositories this morning." from https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/7951#issuecomment-630962149